Git push doesn't push to a new repository
Summary of what I have done:

I have cloned a public repo from a github account and made changes to it

created a new repository on my github
Now I try to push these changes to a new repo on my github but I can't seem to get it right

in order to push this cloned repo to my github I followed these steps:



git remote add origin https://github.com/<my_github>/<my_project>.git

NOTE: after this step I did "git remote -v" and I removed the "upstream" remote which was a way to pull/fetch from the original repo and only kept the "origin" remote

git add .
git commit -m ""
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
This push always writes 100% of the objects but ends in the console with:
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
I have tried "git push --set-upstream origin main" and it ends the same way.

Someone please help me get this cloned repo onto my new empty repository on github.

You might try this:
git config http.postBuffer 524288000

Taken from Git fails when pushing commit to github
Then try again

@Nicholas, I have tried it before, doesn't work. I also tried "git config https.postBuffer 1048576000". Didn't work either. Maybe I am doing it wrong?
